# Ошибка при использовании относительного пути вместо абсолютного в json файле

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, сервер, npm

В чем моя ошибка в синтаксисе, использующим относительный путь
   вместо абсолютного в json файле?

---

Есть папка **"server"** в ней установлен **http server** и **package.json**.
В ней же находится папка  **"webdir"** с веб страницей.

Я могу зайти через консоль в папку **"webdir"** и набрать команду `node [абсолютный путь до файла, запускающего сервер: (.....)/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server]`.

Я хочу чтобы другой пользователь, скачав мой **mpn package** с сайто и сервером, мог сразу после этого набрать команду `mpn start` и у него активировался бы сервер и открылась веб-страница по адресу `localhost:8080`.

Я смог сделать запуск сервера по команде `npm start`, (предварительно открыв через консоль папку **"webdir"**)дописав ее в package.json и используя абсолютный путь к http-server.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node (.....)/server/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server"
  },
```

Это работает.

Но путь будет у разных пользователей разным. Я попробовал указать относительный путь, так как я должен активировать сервер из папки "webdir", путь выглядит так: `../node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server`
я получаю ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему это происходит и как ее исправить?

Comment: так а по указанному пути есть этот модуль? может просто неправильный относительный путь?

Comment: @Grundy путь - скопированный абсолютный путь, но вместо первой части, вплоть до папки "server" - ../ - затем идет название папки, которая находится на одном уровне с папкой webdir и т.д.

Comment: я имел ввиду путь на который он ругается: cannot find module `'(...)/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server'` совпадает с абсолютным путем?

Comment: @Grundy Да, путь совпадает. Не сделал ли я ошибки в синтаксисе? ../ для выхода на уровень выше (из папки webdir), дальше путь такой же.

Comment: Попробуйте так
"start": "node http-server"
т.е. без указания пути. При использовании секции scripts node автоматически сканирует папку bin проекта